# How can I get gg=G in vim to ignore a comma?

Tags: json, vim, macvim, auto-indent

I have autoindent and smartindent in vim turned on, but nocindent turned off.  I'm trying to indent some JSON text without pretty-printing the whole thing, which would be too intrusive:

```
{
  "a" : "value1",
  "b": "value2",
  "c": "value3",
  ...
```

Gets formatted by gg=G as:

```
{
  "a" : "value1",
    "b": "value2",
    "c": "value3",
    ...
```

What's the logic going on there, and what options can I set to fix it, if it's possible?  I tried toggling options like autoindent, smartindent, and cindent (with their "no" counterparts), but it doesn't have an effect on the = command.  My latest attempt had these options:

```
autoindent
smartindent
nocindent
cinoptions=
indentexpr=
indentkeys=0{,0},:,0#,!^F,o,O,e
```

Comment: For an alternative JSON pretty printing solution take a look at python's `json.tool`. I made a quick vim command: `command! -range -nargs=0 -bar JsonTool <line1>,<line2>!python -m json.tool`. Now you can just do `:%JsonTool` to reformat the whole buffer.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I originally did.. using that python command.  It was too intrusive though, putting array elements on separate lines, for instance.  The limited built-in indenter actually fit the bill better, especially with abjuk's solution.  Thanks though... it's neat to learn about that command! technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can explain the logic, but I'm not sure of an easy fix.  Vim's internal indenter is following C-style syntax, so since the `"a" : "value1",` line doesn't end with a `;` it assumes that the following lines are a continuation of that statement and they should be indented to show that.

`:help C-indenting` goes into great depth discussing the various indent options and how they interact.  I skimmed it and nothing jumped out at me, but it's worth a read.

If you have an external formatter that better recognizes the structure of your code, you can always set `equalprg` to run that instead of using the internal formatter.

Edit:  On second thought, `set cinoptions+=+0` will disable indenting for line continuation.  This will also affect regular code, but it might be a reasonable tradeoff depending which annoys you more.  You can also set it per filetype if you're editing standalone .json files.

Comment: How does all that apply to the OP, who has `:set nocindent`?

Comment: Right, but he's using `gg=G` to format the whole file, that uses the C-indenter regardless (unless he has `equalprg` set to something).  `cindent` only matters for auto-indenting while typing.  `cinoptions` affects `=` as well.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in indent settings won't totally cover a complex, non-C language like JSON. Better use a tailored indent setting, like the `indent/json.vim` indent plugin that is part of [vim-json](http://github.com/rogerz/vim-json).

Comment: I do agree that it's silly to format json with the built-in indenter, but it was more convenient to solve an immediate need, where I didn't want to muck with how I had the JSON formatted by hand.  @abjuk's suggestion solved my immediate need, but I still will give you the +10 upvote, which you don't need anyway :)